# Can't upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04.5 (precise pangolin) to 14.04.1 (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04.5 (LTS) and want to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.1 (LTS).

Unfortunately, when I open up the `update-manager` it gives me an option to upgrade to 
 12.10, I don't want to do this since I've heard that it is perfectly possible to upgrade between LTS versions. `do-dist-upgrade` also ends up telling me the same thing. 
Is there any possible way to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.1 from 12.04.5?

Answer (score 1):

Open the updatemanager and click on the settings-button (left bottom of the screen) . 
Now seek for the tab 'updates' and click the selector on the last line (...newer versions of Ubuntu) for LTS (not any version, but only the LTS-version) . You'll be prompted for your password to make the changes valid.

Run again for updates (with good working internet-connection) you should see now the possibility for an upgrade to the next LTS-version (do so) / From there on follow the on-screen instructions.

Mind you: I'd like to give you the advise to do a fresh install of 14.04 LTS ; not only is it much quicker to do, but it is technically better to run a 'clean' installation of this Ubuntu-version (you'll have a 100% good working Ubuntu). Upgrades can go wrong sadly.

So, before you do anything: MAKE BACK UPS of your important data !!!

Good Luck !